# Writing/Converting Meteor Synchronous Functions

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, synchronization, node-fibers

This has been bothering me for a while so I thought I'd just do a quick QA on it:

If one has a normal nodeJS module or something and it has a async function on the server side. How do I make it synchronous. E.g how would I convert the nodejs `fs.stat` asynchronous function to a synchronous one.

e.g I have

**server side js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    getStat:function() {
        fs.stat('/tmp/hello', function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result)
        });
    }
});
```

If I call it from the client I get back `undefined` as my result because the result is in a callback.

Answer (score 7):

There is a function (undocumented) called `Meteor.wrapAsync`.

Simply wrap the function up

```
Meteor.methods({
    getStat:function() {
        var getStat = Meteor._wrapAsync(fs.stat);

        return getStat('/tmp/hello');
    }
});
```

Now you will get the result of this in the `result` of your `Meteor.call`. You can convert any async function that has a callback where the first parameter is an error and the second the result.

Comment: @zimt28 it will throw errors instead of passing them via a callback, you can use `try.. catch` to check them